# is there a way to put html code in a file_put_contents() function?

Tags: php, html, sql, function, variables

it just says:

> file_get_contents("lot of html"): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\timups-html\admin.php on line 88

is there a way to put the HTML inside the function without the error?
here is my code:

```php
if (isset($_POST["category"])) {
  $Category = $_POST["category"];
  $ProductName =  $_POST["productname"];
  $Description = $_POST["description"];
  $optitle =  $_POST["optitle"];
  $op1 = $_POST["op1"];
  $op2 =  $_POST["op2"];
  $op3 = $_POST["op3"];
  $price =  $_POST["Price"];
  $productno = "SELECT productno FROM productno";
  // $header = include 'style/header.php';
  $file_destination = 'Categorys/products/4.php';

  $script = '<?php'.$header.'?>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style2.css" />
      <main class="container">
      <!-- Left Column / Headphones Image -->
      <div class="left-column">
        <img data-image="black" src="../../images/hammer.png" alt="">
        <img data-image="blue" src="../../images/hammer.png" alt="">
        <img data-image="red" class="active" src="../../images/hammer.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <!-- Right Column -->
      <div class="right-column">
        <!-- Product Description -->
        <div class="product-description">
          <span>'.$Category.'</span>
          <h1>'.$ProductName.'</h1>
          <p>'.$Description.'</p>
        </div>
        <!-- Product Configuration -->
        <div class="product-configuration">
          <!-- Cable Configuration -->
          <div class="cable-config">
            <span>'.$optitle.'</span>
            <div class="cable-choose">
              <button>'.$op1.'</button>
              <button>'.$op2.'</button>
              <button>'.$op3.'</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Product Pricing -->
        <div class="product-price">
          <span>'.$price.'</span>
          <a href="#" class="cart-btn">Add to cart</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      </main>';

  $content = file_get_contents($script);
  file_put_contents('Categorys/products/4.php', $content);

$sql = "UPDATE productno SET productno = productno + 1"
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
}
```

Comment: `file_get_contents` will read a file - not a string like you have here so `file_put_contents('Categorys/products/4.php', $script);` might be more appropriate

Comment: Why do you need `file_get_contents` here after all? What is the expected result?

Comment: Do you realize you're wasting people's time just because you used a function without even taking the time to read the manual?

Answer (score 1):

You can put any string content you like via `file_put_contents`.

You don't need to do a `file_get_contents` before. I do not know what you are trying to achieve with this line. Please try it like this:

```
//$content = file_get_contents($script); // remove this line
file_put_contents('Categorys/products/4.php', $script);
```

You may call `file_get_contents($path_to_file)` to load the contents of an existing file into a variable. The parameter you pass into that function must be the local path to an existing file.
Please read the [docs for file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

You may call `file_put_contents` to write some data into a file which may already exist or not. If not it will be created.
Please read the [docs for file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)